# Can two different objects be identical?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In the book I am reading I have been given multiple definitions of the identity relation, they are,

> 1. a=b if a and b are identical
> 2. a=b if a and b refer to the same object

and for the negation of identity I was given,

> 3. a=b is false if a and b refer to different objects.

I am confused because 1 and 2 seem like they mean different things. With definition 1 you could have two different objects, one named 'a' and one named 'b', but with the exact same properties so that they are identical and a=b would be true however a=b would also be false by definition 3 since they are two different objects. I think I might be misinterpreting the definition of 'identical' since no proper definition was given in the book.

Could you please tell me which definition is the correct one?

Comment: my (perhaps unpopular) opinion: this doesn't matter at all

Comment: my (perhaps popular) opinion: maybe read a different book

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Could you please explain why?

Comment: It's possible the distinction between 1 and 2 is a distinction between syntactic equality and semantic equality, but it is hard to tell without context and ideally there'd be some notational distinction somehow, e.g. $a\equiv b$ and $a=b$ or $a=b$ and $[\![a]\!]=[\![b]\!]$.

Comment: [When Is One Thing Equal To Some Other Thing](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/when_is_one.pdf) is an interesting read and perhaps a too-deep look at this question

Comment: If they are identical they refer to the same thing. So 1. is subsumed by 2.

Comment: "Can two different objects be identical?"  According to your book, no.  Henry Smith can only be identical to the president of the orchid club if Henry Smith *IS* the president of the orchid club.

Comment: my (very popular among my fellow Betelguiseans) opinion is you should avoid using "identical".  It's ambiguous at best.  If it means the same object, then it isn't a comparison.  If it means two different objects with identical properties, there should be a more specific definition (such as "congruent" or "equi-area" or whatever) but just *which* properties must be identical.

Comment: What book are you reading? If sounds like $a$ and $b$ are names that refer to objects.

Comment: @JohnDouma They are names, I should have specified that. I am reading _A Modern Formal Logic Primer_ by Paul Teller.

Comment: @Lachie The author is saying two names are equal when they are either the same name or they are two different names that refer to the same object.

Comment: Is any of this relevant to solving any mathematics problems?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Not in the book I am reading, it's so I can understand the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the properties of $a$ is the object to which it refers.  That is, if both $a$ and $b$ have all the same properties, then they refer to the same object.

We can relax this and talk about equivalence classes of objects, but the logical identity is as strict as one can make.  If there is any property that discriminates between the two of them, they aren't identical.

Comment: I don't understand how names can have different truth values. The book I am reading says that only objects affect the truth value of a predicate (which is what I assume you mean by property).

Comment: Or do you mean that the object that $a$ refers to has the property of being that object?

Comment: It would be something like this:  If $A$ is the object to which $a$ refers, then there is a $P(x) = x \text{ refers to } A.$  This means that $P(a)$ is assumed to be true, so if $a=b,$ then $P(b)$ is also true.  (my syntax may be off, but hopefully the intent is understood)

Answer (score 1):

"Can two different objects be identical?"

No.

Just no.

At least according to your book.

> With definition 1 you could have two different objects, one named 'a' and one named 'b', but with the exact same properties so that they are identical

I don't blame you for thinking that is what the definition *seems* like.  But it clear from context that according to *this* book, that is simply not possible.

No two different objects have the exact same properties.  The only way that the thing named 'a' and thing named 'b' have exactly the same properties is if 'a' and 'b' are just two names for the same thing.  If 'a' and 'b' were different things they'd have at least *one* different property.

At least according to this book.

And, as mentioned, in a comment.  If you have a specific object, say this coffee mug in my hand.  Then *one* of the properties it has is "is the specific thing that it is; *this* coffee mug in my hand".  Now you might have another coffee mug that is in every other aspect exactly like mine.  But when it comes the the property "is the specific thing that it is" yours has a different property; it is *your* mug.  Mine has the property; it is *my* mug.  So that is *one* property they do not have in common.

Comment: Just for clarification, is what you're saying in the last paragraph is that every object has the unique property of being that specific object?

Comment: Well, can you deny it?  Mathematical objects can only exist to the degree we can describe them.  I'd have simply just stated the second definition and left it at that.

Comment: I agree, I was just asking if I was interpreting what you said correctly.